# Got "Error in ans\$res: \$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when rolling forecast using rugarch

Tags: forecasting

I used the ugarchroll in rugarch packages and got a strange error:

> `Error in ans$res: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

But I don't have `$` in my code:

```
library(rugarch)
spec = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1),
       submodel = NULL , external.regressors = NULL, variance.targeting = FALSE),
      mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(2,0), include.mean = F, archm = F,
      archpow = 1,arfima = F, external.regressors = NULL, archex = FALSE),start.pars = list(), fixed.pars
      = list(),distribution.model = "norm")

rollgarch_n=ugarchroll(spec,data1return, n.ahead = 1, forecast.length = 500,
   refit.every = 21,refit.window = "moving", solver = "hybrid", solver.control = 
     list(trace = TRUE),calculate.VaR = TRUE, VaR.alpha = 0.01, 
   keep.coef = TRUE)
```

Comment: When I run your code with `data1return <- rnorm(1000)` no errors are reported. Could you please provide the output of `sessionInfo()` and sample data?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same error until I realized I had some NAs in the series of returns I was trying to model/forecast. After removing NAs the code worked perfectly. I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: please put such "answers" as comments

Comment: I have encountered the same error, with no nulls in my data, so there is definitely still a problem here.